# Call another bash script from my bash script, give it some input values

Tags: linux, bash, shell, arguments

I have a simple bash script which calls another script 10 times:

```
#!/bin/sh

val=10
for i in `seq $val`
do
       ./script2.sh flename$i
done
```

`script2.sh` take 2 input parameters (not cmd arguments, two input variables) (for me it does not matter what parameters, they can be just some 2 identical strings). Now = how can I pass those 2 identical strings to my `script2.sh` in my `for` loop?

I tried this:

`./script2.sh flename$i | string1 | string1`

but it does not work as I want it to.

Comment: What are you using `|` for?

Comment: why not just export two environment variables? can you show script2.sh to have a better understanding of what you are trying to do?

Comment: What does "two input variables" mean? Does `script2.sh` read two lines from standard input? Does it assume particular variables will be present in its environment?

Comment: This is not a bash script, it is an *sh* script. If you change the shebang to `#!/bin/bash` it opens up a lot of possibilities for different approaches (at the cost of portability). If you intend this to be a shell script, you should remove the word "bash" from your question and tags. Otherwise, you should change the shebang.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for that would be something like

```
printf '%s\n' "$string1" "$string2" | ./script2.sh filename"$i"
```

You could also use a here document:

```
./script2.sh filename"$i" <<____HERE
$string1
$string2
____HERE
```

Some people will tell you `echo` but it has various portability issues etc; `printf` is uniformly standard and safer. But if it's just two static lines of string, you can certainly do

```
echo 'string1
string2' | ./script2.sh filename "$i"
```

(yes, that is a single-quoted string with a newline in the middle) or somewhat less efficiently

```
( echo string1; echo string2 ) | ./script2.sh filename"$i"
```

The general syntax of a pipeline is `command1 | command2 | command...` so what you had would not work unless `string1` was a command which produced the desired output. (This is not impossible to do, but probably not a good idea in this particular scenario.) But on top of that, you were piping the output from the script to `string1` where you clearly want vice versa.

Any command which produces suitable output can be used to feed the pipeline; if you need lots of input, try `yes`, which exists specifically for this purpose;

```
yes string1 | head -n 2 | ./script2.sh filename"$i"
```

Here, `yes` prints an endless sequence of `string1` lines (well, it ends when the pipeline is closed by `head`); `head` passes through just the first two.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use

```
./script2.sh flename$i "string1" "string2"
```

Then in script2, filename$i will be available as $1, string1 as $2, and string2 as $3